# kml GroundOverlay href of image with two '=' within the url

Tags: kml, url

I wish to provide a lightweight kml (to be zipped to a kmz)
containing GroundOverlays of the [NASA MODIS subsets across the Alaskan Arctic waters](https://lance.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?project=other).  Recipients must be able to receive this kmz over a very limited bandwidth, and then select the GroundOverlay of choice 
(for their field study region; cloud-free day; and desired resolution).
For years my kml worked without a glitch, however last fall NASA reorganized their url to include two "**=**" symbols

(example: https://lance.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?project=other&subset=BeringSea.2017079.terra.721.2km.jpg).

When I pass this as the target of my kml GroundOverlay href, I get an error message indicating a "not well informed (invalid token)" at the position of the second "=" symbol within the href url in the example kml below.

Please advise with strategies to restore this GroundOverlay function to the offending url's.

Example GroundOverlay kml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
 xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
 <Folder>
 <name>Sea Ice Data for field opperational use only
 <br>Updated 2017 Mar 20 12:39 </br>
 </name>
 <open>1</open>
 <LookAt>
 <longitude>-163</longitude>
 <latitude>71</latitude>
 <altitude>0</altitude>
 <range>2500000</range>
 <tilt>0</tilt>
 <heading>0</heading>
 </LookAt>
 <Folder>
 <Style><ListStyle><listItemType>radioFolder</listItemType></ListStyle></Style>
 <name>MODIS  BeringSea terra </name>
 <open>0</open>
 <Folder>
 <Style><ListStyle><listItemType>radioFolder</listItemType></ListStyle></Style>
 <name>MODIS  BeringSea 2km terra </name>
 <GroundOverlay>
<name>MOD2k_Ber_2017-Mar-21</name>
 <open>0</open>
 <visibility>1</visibility>
 <color>ffffffff</color>
 <Icon>
<href>https://lance.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?project=other&subset=BeringSea.2017079.terra.721.2km.jpg</href>
 <refreshMode>onChange</refreshMode>
 </Icon>
<LatLonBox id="khLatLonBoxMODIS_BeringSea">
<north>70</north>
<south>58</south>
<east>-155</east>
 <west> -190 </west>
 </LatLonBox>
 </GroundOverlay>
  </Folder>
 </Folder>
 </Folder>
 </kml>
```

Comment: Following a suggestion from NASA's MODIS support staff, I have updated the href url to   https://lance.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?subset=BeringSea.2017079.terra.721.2km.jpg   Oddly, this resolves from a browser (tested with both Chrome and I.E.), but does not display (large red X is displayed over its bounding box) from the kml from Google Earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue with the image URL you're requesting isn't the equal sign(s), but rather the ampersand.  Replace the & with & and it should work for you.

That said, you have a bunch of other things in the KML you shared which are not schema compliant or not best practices.

1. Top-level Folder, name tag contains HTML br tags - not best practice, but shouldn't break anything. Just make sure to either wrap the contents of the name tag in CDATA, or escape the brackets in the HTML tags.
2. LookAt child tag order should be lon, lat, alt, heading, tilt, range.
3. 2nd level Folder - Style section should come after name & open tags.
4. 3rd level Folder - Style section should come after name tag.
5. GroundOverlay - visibility tag comes between name tag and open tag.
6. LatLonBox, west tag - remove spaces from around the number.
7. LatLonBox, west tag - technically -190 is not schema-valid, but if you replace it with the equivalent 170, the image wraps around the earth the wrong direction. I'm not sure what the correct way to deal with that is, so recommend leaving it since it works in Earth.

Below is updated KML with the working URL, recommended updates, and indentation for legibility.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"> 
<Folder>
    <name><![CDATA[Sea Ice Data for field opperational use only<br>Updated 2017 Mar 20 12:39 </br>]]></name>
    <open>1</open>
    <LookAt>
        <longitude>-163</longitude>
        <latitude>71</latitude>
        <altitude>0</altitude>
        <heading>0</heading>
        <tilt>0</tilt>
        <range>2500000</range>
    </LookAt>
    <Folder>
        <name>MODIS  BeringSea terra </name>
        <open>0</open>
        <Style><ListStyle><listItemType>radioFolder</listItemType></ListStyle></Style>
        <Folder>
            <name>MODIS  BeringSea 2km terra </name>
            <Style><ListStyle><listItemType>radioFolder</listItemType></ListStyle></Style>
            <GroundOverlay>
                <name>MOD2k_Ber_2017-Mar-21</name>
                <visibility>1</visibility>
                <open>0</open>
                <color>ffffffff</color>
                <Icon>
                    <href>https://lance.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?project=other&amp;subset=BeringSea.2017079.terra.721.2km.jpg</href>
                    <refreshMode>onChange</refreshMode>
                </Icon>
                <LatLonBox id="khLatLonBoxMODIS_BeringSea">
                    <north>70</north>
                    <south>58</south>
                    <east>-155</east>
                    <west>-190</west>
                </LatLonBox>
            </GroundOverlay>
        </Folder>
    </Folder>
</Folder>
</kml>
```

Rather than create your own KMLs, it might be easier to just grab the ready-made KMZ versions that NASA provides on their site.  For example, on the page for your subset: [BeringSea.BeringSea.2017079.terra.721.2km](https://lance.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?project=other&subset=BeringSea.BeringSea.2017079.terra.721.2km), they link to [this KMZ file](https://lance.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?project=other&subset=BeringSea.2017079.terra.721.2km.kmz), which includes the image bundled inside. Since you said your users are bandwidth limited, you might be worried about the larger size of that KMZ file over your KML, but remember it already contains the same image that your users will need to download anyway, so should be the same overall download size.

Comment: Both your suggestion for improving my kml, and for simply offering my email recipients direct links to the NASA served kmz files are helpful.   Due to a change in the NASA server from http to https, I was unable to get my script-built kml/z's to work.  I now simply provide a table of links to the NASA kmz's (e.g. [Chukchi Sea 2 km Terra] (https://lance.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?project=other&subset=BeaufortSouthWest.2017129.terra.721.2km.kmz).   This enables my users ready access to just the data that they need and uses minimum bandwidth.